# AWS SDK SNS subscribe to https endpoint

Tags: php, aws-sdk, amazon-sns

Trying to subscribe to Amazon SNS via the SDK. Currently, I can createTopic via the SDK but when trying to subscribe to an endpoint the result is an XML parser error. It seems that everything I'm doing is correct yet nothing works.

The code

```
`/* createTopic working, populates $topic with TopicArn correctly */

$topic = $result['TopicArn'];
$protocol = 'https';
$endpoint = 'https://oursytem.domain.com/api/endpoint'

try {
    $result = $SnSclient->subscribe([
        'Protocol' => $protocol,
        'Endpoint' => $endpoint,
        'ReturnSubscriptionArn' => true,
        'TopicArn' => $topic,
    ]);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($result);
} catch (AwsException $e) {
    // output error message if fails
    error_log($e->getMessage());
}`
```

The trace:

```
`TraceMiddleware.php:268:
array (size=6)
    'instance' =\> string '00000000503a6f0b000000003c8b00da' (length=32)
    'class' =\> string 'Aws\\Api\\Parser\\Exception\\ParserException' (length=40)
    'message' =\> string 'Error parsing XML: String could not be parsed as XML' (length=52)
    'file' =\> string 'C:\\wamp64\\www\\awstest\\vendor\\aws\\aws-sdk-php\\src\\Api\\Parser\\PayloadParserTrait.php' (length=82)
    'line' =\> int 49
    'trace' =\> string '#0 C:\\wamp64\\www\\awstest\\vendor\\aws\\aws-sdk-php\\src\\Api\\Parser\\QueryParser.php(43): Aws\\Api\\Parser\\QueryParser->parseXml(Object(GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Stream), Object(GuzzleHttp\\Psr7\\Response))
`
```

Any thoughts? Already read a lot of docs and nothing seems to fit.

Regards.

Comment: the only thing I see missing is that compared to what I see in doc, is that you are not setting your SnsClient to a region, profile and version similar to what the documentation has, not sure if that helps.

Comment: @NMAK SNSClient is set to region, profile and version so it is not that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in the SDK: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/issues/2572.

This should be resolved in `3.246.1`.